# Adding custom code to greenDAO entities

Tags: android, orm, greendao

I want to add some custom code to my greenDAO entities. I saw there is something like protected regions. But I don't like the idea to check in the generated classes to my git repository. I'd like to use inheritance for this.

i.e. I have an entity `User`. So I want greenDAO to generate a class called `UserBase`. This I want to extend by `User` and implement a method like this:

```
public String getFullName() {
    return this.first + " " + this.last;
}
```

Where `first` and `last` are managed properties.

But I have no idea how to tell greenDAO to use the class `User` instead of the generated entity `UserBase`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you put `getFullName` method in UserBase ?

Comment: because then I have to checkin the generated file into my git. But the biggest part of the class is generated and does not need to be checked in. You do not checkin the R.java either, don#t you?

Comment: nope, but I add my generated classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way how to solve this:

you can enter a parent for each entity:

```
Entity user = schema.addEntity("User");
...
user.setSuperclass("UserBase");
```

So you can implement the `UserBase` as an abstract class.

```
public abstract class UserBase {

  public String getFullName() {
    return getFirst() + " " + getLast();
  }

  public abstract int getFirst();
  public abstract int getLast();
}
```

The disadvantage here is, that you have to declare the generated getters as abstract methods to access them.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I had the same exact issue and this is GOLD! I was struggling to extend my Dao as well until you posted this method.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution. But for me I wanted to override an automatic getter and this superclass solution will not do it :-(

Answer (score 7):

The common approach is to use "keep sections" in the generated entities. Keep sections allow to add members and methods directly in the generated entity. Check here for details:
http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/modelling-entities/

Comment: "Keep sections" or in MDD terms "protected regions" have several disadvantages:  

* you have to checkin the generated code into you vcs  
* you have to keep the code clean. somewhere has to be a signature for keep section. If you break this signature (like an accident or code formatting) you will loose you code